# Cтоит ли использовать кортеж в aliases?

Tags: python, discord.py, теория

Вроде кортежи куда эффективнее списков в плане "чтения", я подумал что в `aliases` куда лучше будет пихать кортеж нежели список. Стоит вопрос насколько это целесообразнее, так как в чужом коде который я успел увидеть используют в основном списки.

Что лучше?

```
@bot.command(aliases = (''))
@bot.command(aliases = [''])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирать между списком и кортежем имеет смысл, когда идет работа с большими и сложными данными. Когда вы передаете просто список строк, разницы в производительности не будет.

Но, так как эти данные все равно только для чтения библиотекой, имеет смысл передавать их именно в виде кортежа

Comment: Субъективно понимание "большие и сложные" данные. Различие кортежа и списка заключается в изменяемости. Нужно смотреть по ситуации в некоторых моментах не возможно использовать кортеж, хотя предпочтения я отдаю именно  им

Comment: @Dmitry соглашусь. Опять же в этом контексте подразумевается только чтение данных из структуры, поэтому использовать кортеж будет более правильно

Comment: я не знаю этой конструкции, указанной в вопросе. Сомнения только в том, что до того как читать, в общем смысле, данные нужно иметь или собрать